# Checking the Numbers Object and it's Properties?

Tags: javascript, object, numbers

I want to have my numbers object property returned with the string "Input number is..." followed by each property "MAX_VALUE", "MIN_VALUE", etc. What would be the best way to go about doing that? This is all I have of code for now, and I also want to check to see if it has any random numbers in the property as well, or if the value is Nan.

```
function whatNumberIsIt(n){
  
  
}
```

Comment: The "all you have" is nothing

Comment: When you want to ask and answer your own question, there's an option for that in the Stack Overflow user interface. That helps keep other people from being confused, as they know what's going on because you provide the question and answer at the same time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many ways to go about doing it, and one of the simpler ways would be to use an "if...else" statement. The "if...else" statement will cycle through each conditional statement to see if it's true in the numbers object. So it will look something like this:

```
function whatNumberIsIt(n){
  //coding here
  var n= Number(n);
  
  if(n == Number.MAX_VALUE){
    return "Input number is Number.MAX_VALUE";
  }
  
  else if(n == Number.MIN_VALUE){
    return "Input number is Number.MIN_VALUE";
  }
   
   }
  else if(n == Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY){
     return "Input number is Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY";
    }
  else if(n == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY){
       return "Input number is Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY";
     } 
}
```

To check and see if the object has a random number or if the value is NaN, you need to use the "isNan()" and "isInteger()" methods:

```
 else if(isNaN(n)){
     return "Input number is Number.NaN";
   }

 else if(Number.isInteger(n)){
    return 'Input number is' +' '+ n;
  }
```